# "could not find suitable fingerprints matched to available hardware" error

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, login, fingerprint

I have a thinkpad t61 with a UPEK fingerprint reader.  I'm running ubuntu 9.10, with fprint installed.  Everything works fine (I am able to swipe my fingerprint to authenticate any permission dialogues or "sudo" prompts successfully) except for actually logging onto my laptop when I boot up or end my session.

I receive an error below the gnome login that says

```
"Could not locate any suitable fingerprints matched to available hardware."
```

What is causing this?

here are the contents of /etc/pam.d/common-auth file

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth sufficient pam_fprint.so
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
# end of pam-auth-update config
#auth sufficient pam_fprint.so
#auth required pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you make your user-dir encrypted when you installed Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment out the following line:
auth sufficient pam_fprint.so

this will remove fingerptint authentication from yor PAM authentication